# Select till caret in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with a div that I've set as `contenteditable`. When I write something like

```
foo
bar

  baz1baz2
```

and set some colors with javascript, its innerHTML is like:

```
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div></div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: red">baz1</span>baz2</div>
```

If I position the caret in the center of baz1, how do I get the text from the beginning till the caret or, in this case:

```
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div></div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: red">ba</span></div>
```

?

**EDIT:**

[Contenteditable - extract text from caret to end of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740640/contenteditable-extract-text-from-caret-to-end-of-element) Seems like a possible solution, but it does not work. Also the provided jsFiddle example is broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contenteditable - extract text from caret to end of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740640/contenteditable-extract-text-from-caret-to-end-of-element)